# LU factorization less efficient than Gauss elimination if only used for one {b} vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Here is my thought process: Gauss elimination requires ~(2n^3)/3 flops for forward elimination and then ~n^2 flops for back substitution. LU factorization requires a forward elimination to obtain the decomposition, then forward substitution and then back substitution to solve. Therefore am I correct in thinking that IF you are only looking to solve to one {b}, Gauss elimination is actually marginally faster (one less substitution, so rather than (2n^3)/3 + 2n^2 + lower order terms, you have (2n^3)/3 + n^2 + lower order terms)? Or does the fact that they both have an n^3 negate this?

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers you give were correct, then both methods would require O($n^3$) operations; the $n^2$ bit is immaterial since the $n^3$ term dominates.

However, it turns out that LU decomposition can be done [faster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Theoretical_complexity) than with forward elimination, it is actually O($n^{2.4}$).

Comment: thanks - so is there no situation in which it would be more efficient to use Gauss elimination than LU decomposition?

Answer (score 0):

If used for only one vector, Gaussian elimination is indeed "faster" than naive LU decomposition.

One must be **very** careful about using the various "divide and conquer" algorithms for LU decomposition, that work in $O(n^{3-\kappa})$ if working in finite-precision arithmetic,  because the stability/accuracy properties are not necessarily very good.  For moderate-sized systems of equations the extra overhead defeats the speedup; for very large systems of equations, there is danger of getting meaningless results.